# Export Flutter Widget Tree and clickable Widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Is there an easy way to export the flutter widget tree with all the properties the widgets have?

I need to export the widget tree to get the coordinates of the widgets on the screen and also the information which widgets are clickable.
Is there a property which indicates if a widget is clickable?

So far I am using the websocket of the debugger to extract the widget tree and I was wondering if the might be an easier way.
Using this method I could not find a way to find out which of the widgets are clickable and which not.

Comment: have you found anything on this?

Comment: No really. I used the RPCs the Flutter Inspector uses to get the widget tree and attributes.

Comment: can you describe it little how you are using it.